# Using StreamWriter is not working

Tags: c#

Good day! I have an error:

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\temps\11.pdf' because it is being used by another process.

What my system wanted to do is to get a report of "clientid" and save it as a pdf on C:\temps\. the pdf file will have a name of "clientid". Lastly is to attach it and send it to my email. the above code is working properly but the code below is not. please help me to make it work.

```
lock (fileLock)
{
    report.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, 
        "C:\\temps\\" + clientid +".pdf");
    report.Dispose();
}

sqlTran.Dispose();
com8.Dispose();
con8.Close();
con8.Dispose();

Attachment files = new Attachment(@"C:\\temps\\" + clientid + ".pdf");
Mailmsg.Attachments.Add(files);
Clients.Send(Mailmsg);
```

I'm beginner. I'm accepting creative criticism and I'm really willing to learn. if you have questions I will reply as fast as I can. Thank you for time.

Comment: What did you expect to happen in this line?  _string stringpath = Convert.ToString(writer);_

Comment: Please format your code properly if you wish for us to read it properly

Comment: I'm redoing my code from the point it is working

Answer (score 3):

If you need to pass a path to ExportToDisk you should get it from your string, not converting the instance of a StreamWriter to a string.
This conversion don't return the name of the file because the StreamWriter doesn't override ToString to return a path and the default ToString in the base class object simply return the full name of the class "System.IO.StreamWriter"

```
lock (fileLock)
{
  string stringpath = Path.Combine(@"C:\temps", clientid+".pdf";

  // If you need the streamwriter then uncomment the lines below
  // using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stringpath))
  // { 
     report.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.
               Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, 
               stringpath );
     report.Dispose();

     Attachment files = new Attachment(stringpath);
     Mailmsg.Attachments.Add(files);

  // end using
  // }
}
```

Comment: awww thank you so much I will try this and as soon as it works Im gonna mark it as solved. this is what I really wanted to do.

Comment: Sir it actually work but when I tried to run my function which is private void test() on my timer1 by typing Task t1 = new Task(()=>test()); then t1.Start(); This error showed up.
Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\temps\11' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: I suspect that you don't need that _using(streamwriter_ This will open and lock the file, so the following export on the same file will fail. I suggest to remove the using if the streamwriter is not needed

Comment: Did you remove the StreamWriter?

Comment: Sorry but I can't tell you exactly. Is the error raised on the new Attachment line? If so it seems that ExportToDisk fails to free the file but this should be a well known problem then. Can you look at the StackTrace of the Exception and try to understand on which line the error happens?. Sorry again but I need to leave now.